# Best way to notify ui what's happening on another thread in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, logging, mvvm

I'm using MVVM, and in my viewmodel I start a thread (it is a server application, so it is a connection thread), and I'm looking for an appropriate way (or ways (!)) to notify the UI about what's happening on another thread. The way I want to do it, to have a textbox of some sort for logs (lines stored in an ObservableCollection probably), and each time something happens on the connection thread, I would want a new line added to the textbox.
Here's how I set the command (the method starts a thread which is listening for connections):

```
public ViewModel()
{
    StartCommand = new RelayCommand(PacketHandler.Start);
}
```

PacketHandler class:

```
    public static void Start()
    {
        var connectionThread = new Thread(StartListening);
        connectionThread.IsBackground = true;
        connectionThread.Start();
    }

    private static void StartListening()
    {
        if (!isInitialized) Initialize();
        try
        {
            listener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                // some kind of logging here which reaches the ui immediately

                var protocol = new Protocol(client);
                var thread = new Thread(protocol.StartCommunicating) { IsBackground = true };
                thread.Start();
                connectedThreads.Add(thread);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // temp
            MessageBox.Show("Error in PacketHandler class");
        }
    }
```

I'm looking for possible solutions, preferably the best. I'm a beginner programmer, so I may not comprehend the most complex solutions, please bear in mind this, too. NOTE: I read about events, observer pattern, and a few other things as possible solutions, only I don't know which (and of course: how) to use them properly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: a producer consumer approach is a good idea for your particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more similar working example

View

```
<Window x:Class="MultipleDataGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <ScrollViewer MaxHeight="100">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ServerLog}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

View CodeBehind

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MultipleDataGrid
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Your ServerThread

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace MultipleDataGrid
{
    public class Something
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            var connectionThread = new Thread(StartListening);
            Log = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Log, _lock);//For Thread Safety
            connectionThread.IsBackground = true;
            connectionThread.Start();
        }

        public static ObservableCollection<string> Log { get; private set; }
        private static readonly object _lock = new object();

        private static void StartListening()
        {
            try
            {
                int i = 0;
                while (i <= 100)
                {
                    Log.Add("Something happened " + i);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    i++;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // temp
                MessageBox.Show("Error in PacketHandler class");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the ViewModel

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MultipleDataGrid
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public ObservableCollection<string> ServerLog { get; private set; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Something.Start();
            Something.Log.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
                {
                    ServerLog = Something.Log;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("ServerLog");
                };
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            var pc = PropertyChanged;
            if (pc != null)
                pc(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it seems to be pretty simple, which is easily understandable - nothing is here which I had never encountered with before. Compared to other answers (observer, blockingcollection), might there be differences in performance?

Comment: The performance is good. you can easily check it. As you can see I have not created any new threads.

Comment: Probably not the most elegant way to do this, but this was the one I could easily make work, so I mark this as an answer. My fault, probably, that I didn't start the project in time. :) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to introduce you to `BlockingCollection<T>` which is a thread-safe collection class that provides the following:

- An implementation of the producer/consumer pattern; `BlockingCollection<T>` is a wrapper for the `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>` interface.
- Concurrent addition and removal of items from multiple threads with the Add and Take methods.
- A bounded collection that blocks Add and Take operations when the collection is full or empty.
- Cancellation of Add or Take operations by using a CancellationToken object in the TryAdd or TryTake method.

here is a simple example for you

```
public static void Start()
{
    var connectionThread = new Thread(StartListening);
    connectionThread.IsBackground = true;
    connectionThread.Start();

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Logger); //start logger thread
}

//thread safe data collection, can be modified from multiple threads without threading issues
static BlockingCollection<string> logData = new BlockingCollection<string>();

public ObservableCollection<string> Logs { get; set; } // to bind to the UI

private void Logger(object state)
{
    //collect everything from the logData, this loop will not terminate until `logData.CompleteAdding()` is called 
    foreach (string item in logData.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        //add the item to the UI bound ObservableCollection<string>
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Logs.Add(item)); 
    }
}

private static void StartListening()
{
    if (!isInitialized) Initialize();
    try
    {
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            // some kind of logging here which reaches the ui immediately
            logData.TryAdd("log"); //adding a log entry to the logData, completely thread safe

            var protocol = new Protocol(client);
            var thread = new Thread(protocol.StartCommunicating) { IsBackground = true };
            thread.Start();
            connectedThreads.Add(thread);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // temp
        MessageBox.Show("Error in PacketHandler class");
    }
}
```

using this approach you can also have multiple threads adding log data without threading issues.

for more info on `BlockingCollection<T>` refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312

**Update**

view model class

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private Dispatcher Dispatcher;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        StartCommand = new RelayCommand(PacketHandler.Start);
        // dispatcher is required for UI updates
        // remove this line and the variable if there is one
        // also assuming this constructor will be called from UI (main) thread
        Dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;  
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Logger); //start logger thread
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Logs { get; set; } // to bind to the UI

    private void Logger(object state)
    {
        //collect everything from the LogData, this loop will not terminate until `CompleteAdding()` is called on LogData 
        foreach (string item in PacketHandler.LogData.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            //add the item to the UI bound ObservableCollection<string>
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Logs.Add(item));
        }
    }
}
```

and packet handler class

```
public class PacketHandler
{
    public static BlockingCollection<string> LogData = new BlockingCollection<string>();

    private static void StartListening()
    {
        if (!isInitialized) Initialize();
        try
        {
            listener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                // some kind of logging here which reaches the ui immediately
                LogData.TryAdd("log"); //adding a log entry to the logData, completely thread safe

                var protocol = new Protocol(client);
                var thread = new Thread(protocol.StartCommunicating) { IsBackground = true };
                thread.Start();
                connectedThreads.Add(thread);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // temp
            MessageBox.Show("Error in PacketHandler class");
        }
    }
}
```

this will work for your case

Comment: Wow, looks like something I've been looking for. Is there a particular reason why the ObservableCollection is not static? Or just a typo?
EDIT: you mention the loop does not terminate until that particular method gets called. Does that mean it gets called when it finishes one  loop, or it means it is adding items constantly all over again when the loop finishes? And unrelated to this: aren't there performance issues if the log has e.g. 10000+ items?

Comment: By the way: does the logger method get called when the collection actually changed?

Comment: As you can see we invoke the logger method only once via ThreadPool, then the loop begins and the loop will continue to run forever untill the CompleteAdding() is called. the loop itself will wait for the item to be added and will continue the execution once added and the container will remove the item from the collection once consumed. and the best part is that it that the GetConsumingEnumerable is thread safe too so you can have multiple thread processing the logData too. Do try the code and see the true beauty of producer and consumer.

Comment: Observable collection is not static, it is a instance property which will be binded to ui. also there is no significant performance loss while using this approach. all what you do manually to make it thread safe it taken over by the BlockingCollection container. also to mention when you use GetConsumingEnumerable it removes the item which is consumed or you can say the item for which the loop has been executed.

Comment: As for being static or not, I could not add the Logger to the queue while the Start method was static and the Logger was not. In the end I've built it up, and as I tried I got NotSupportedException, saying the this source collection can't been modified from other threads (I did not modify your code). Though I made it work with the other answer, I still want to find out what was wrong with my code. Do you happen to have any idea? (I changed my code last night, but I can reproduce it just for the problem's sake.

Comment: There was issue in the previous code for your particular case, I tried it bit differently during my tests. I did try to update it for your case. just give it a try and let me know your feel about it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MVVM and want to create a thread to perform a given task and report back some progress to the UI without cross-threaded exceptions, you can use `SOLID` principles to create a `MyWorker` class that looks like this...

```
public class MyWorker : IObservable<string>, IDisposable
{
    private Task _task;
    private IObserver<string> _observer; 
    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<string> observer)
    {
        _observer = observer;
        return this;
    }
    public void StartWork()
    {
        _task = new Task(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // background work goes here
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                if (_observer != null)
                {
                    string status = DateTime.Now.ToString("G");
                    _observer.OnNext(status);
                }
            }
        });
        _task.ContinueWith(r =>
        {
            if (_observer != null)
            {
                _observer.OnCompleted();
            }
        });
        _task.Start();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_task != null)
        {
            _task.Dispose();
            _task = null;
        }
    }
}
```

It is a light-weight encapsulation of the background task.  The class simply creates a Task and reports back the time every two seconds.  It uses the IObservable pattern, which provides push notifications.  It is documented here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

A simple ViewModel that instantiates this class looks like this...

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IObserver<string>
{
    readonly ListCollectionView _listCollectionView;
    public ViewModel()
    {
        LogEntries = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        _listCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(LogEntries) as ListCollectionView;
        if (_listCollectionView != null)
        {
            MyWorker worker = new MyWorker();
            worker.Subscribe(this);
            worker.StartWork();
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> LogEntries { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var handler = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref PropertyChanged, null, null);
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    public void OnNext(string logEntry)
    {
        _listCollectionView.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => LogEntries.Add(logEntry));
    }
    public void OnCompleted()
    {
        // clean up goes here
    }
    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
        // error handling goes here
    }
}
```

The only difference between this VM and your VM is that this one implements the IObserver pattern, which provides a mechanism for receiving push-based notifications.  The docs are here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Because it's simple, the VM starts the thread in the constructor.  In your case, you would start the thread in the `Execute` delegate of your StartCommand.  The VM above works with a collection of strings, hence the need for a dispatcher.  Fortunately the dispatcher is provided out-of-the-box by the `ListCollectionView` class.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.aspx  If instead, you are updating a string property then the dispatcher is not needed because the binding engine does the marshalling for you.

With these two classes, a small application can be made with this Xaml...

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding LogEntries}"/>
</Grid>
```

When the application is run, the ListBox will be updated every two seconds with no threading conflicts while maintaining a responsive UI.

Note:  I built the application under .NET 4.5, and the MINIMUM version is .NET 4.0.  It will work **without** Rx.    If you decide to go with the full RX, you can take advantage of the ObserveOn method which gives further streamlining to multi-threaded applications.  You can use the NuGet manager from within Visual Studio to install the full Reactive Extensions.

Comment: Thank you for describing the approach, but the application being actually a server - quite long running operation - is it a good idea to do the work in the threadpool?

Comment: @csakii, the pattern itself is agnostic whether the work is done in the thread pool, or a parameterized start delegate (like yours), or the TPL.  I like the Task (from TPL) for this sort of thing because it has more flexibility: can be gracefully cancelled and can have specific continuation options.  Plus if the task is long-running, the task manager will move it to a thread pool in the appdomain so that local threads will not starve out.  Choice is yours.